# Java: How exactly are character models and the like created in LWJGL?

Tags: java, lwjgl

Think about the games like Spiral Knights and Minecraft(Which I believe both use LWJGL) - How are the characters created? Does, at least Spiral Knights, use some other outside program to make them, then import them somehow? Does Minecraft handle their mob / character creation all in Java or LWJGL(That would make sense to me, since the models are more simple)? I'm confused as to how and where they're made, and the different ways you go about making them. I'm not talking about textures, but the things that the textures are applied to.

Does making the models even use LWJGL?

Please tell me if I misunderstood something, or said something incorrectly that didn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty hard to say without knowing what each individual team's art pipeline looks like. As such I won't try to speculate except to say that as long as you can render 3d geometry, you can surely find or build a routine to import just about any 3d file format: collada, max, maya (mb, ma), .x, ms3d, blend, etc.

The need to consider just 3 things:

- Does the 3d tool you're considering support the kind of art you want to create?
- Do you or your artist have experience in that tool?
- Can you write or find the code to load the 3d file format?

If you can answer those 3 questions positively, then you have a good candidate for the tool to use for this project :-)

Comment: Ah, so as long as I can render what the tool creates in java, it's the abilities of the specific tools that matters. And, of course, the experience part.

To do now is to look for a program that has what I need to work with.

Thanks for editing my post to include the 'game-development' tag as well, I wasn't aware that existed.